PHP form submitted returning empty isset($_POST["submit"])
PHP form submitted returning empty  isset($_POST["submit"]) . Frame work used in this form is bootstrap html form . What could be the issue in this form fields as i am new to this php work .
Any expert suggestion would be greatly welcome . please find the below form code


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<form action="registration-logic.php" method="POST" id="registerform">
  <div class="form-row m-b-55">
    <div class="name">Name</div>
    <div class="value">
      <div class="row row-space">
        <div class="col-2">
          <div class="input-group-desc">
            <input class="input--style-5" type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name">
            <label for="first_name" class="label--desc">first name</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <div class="input-group-desc">
            <input class="input--style-5" type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name">
            <label for="last_name" class="label--desc">last name</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="name">EMail ID</div>
    <div class="value">
      <label for="emailid" class="label--desc"></label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="input--style-5" type="email" name="emailid" id="emailid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="name">Mobile Number</div>
    <label for="emailid" class="label--desc"></label>
    <div class="value">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="input--style-5" type="text" id="mobilenumber" name="mobilenumber">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row ">
    <label class="label label--block">is Whats app Number?</label>
    <div class="p-t-15">
      <label for="whatsappnumber" class="radio-container m-r-55">Yes
        <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="whatsappnumber" name="whatsappnumber">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="radio-container">No
        <input type="radio" name="whatsappnumber" id="whatsappnumber">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="name">Password</div>
    <label for="setpassword" class="label--desc"></label>
    <div class="value">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="input--style-5" type="password" id="setpassword" name="setpassword">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="name">Confirm Password</div>
    <label for="confirmpassword" class="label--desc"></label>
    <div class="value">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="input--style-5" type="password" id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--red" type="submit">Register</button> &nbsp; If Already Registered <a href="login.php">Please Login</a>
  </div>
</form>




<button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--red" type="submit" > doesn't have name="submit". Without a name, a form field (or button)'s value is not sent to the server when the form is submitted. This is just the basics of HTML forms and has nothing to do with PHP, mysql or bootstrap.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form#sending_form_data_to_your_web_server

BUT: Do NOT give the name "submit" if you ever plan on doing some JavaScript related submitting. Use something else, like name="subbut"

I made you a snippet, I assumed bootstrap, but I do not recognise the -- in the attributes - is that due to BEM or something?
